# setting cookies

Tags: ruby, http, cookies, rack

Okay, so I'm trying to set cookies using Ruby. I'm in a Rack environment. `response[name]=value` will add an HTTP header into the HTTP headers hash rack has. I know that it works.

But the following method of setting cookies doesn't work:

> ```
>   def set_cookie(opts={})
>     args = {
>       :name     => nil,
>       :value    => nil,
>       :expires  => Time.now+314,
>       :path     => '/',
>       :domain    => Cambium.uri #contains the IP address of the dev server this is running on
>     }.merge(opts)
>     raise ArgumentError, ":name and :value are mandatory" if args[:name].nil? or args[:value].nil?
>     response['Set-Cookie']="#{args[:name]}=#{args[:value]}; expires=#{args[:expires].clone.gmtime.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")}; path=#{args[:path]}; domain=#{args[:domain]}"
>  end
> ```

Why not? And how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you access your site by the IP address of the machine or by a domain name?

Comment: By IP address right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't use an IP address with cookies, at least not with also specifying a port.